# regular expressions- not including a character

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to capture the value for name from query string with regular expression; I have done the folowing:

```
/name=(.*)/g

example: ?name=foo&bar=baz
```

But this grabs all string to the end; I know `^` is used for not; but I could not figure out the right syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use regex you can use a non greedy operator like this:

```
name=(.*?)&
```

Btw, you can also you another regex like this to cover more cases:

```
name=(.*?)(?:&|$)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qZ7rS0/1)**

Javascript code:

```
var re = /name=(.*?)(?:&|$)/gm; 
var str = 'example: ?name=foo&bar=baz\nexample: ?name=foo\nexample: ?bar=baz&name=foo';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: No, you don't *have* to, there are other options.

Comment: And what function returns match in javascript; I know `match` and `test`, but they are for testing if it matches or not

Comment: @user3399784 have just updated the answer with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `/name=([^&]+)/` if you only have one or use global modifier for more